# Build a multidimensional array from a single level XML file

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**Problem**

I have been trying to build a new array from a single array in which i need to get `Level 1's` at the top level, then `Level 2` in of each of their parent `Level 1's` and then finally all `Level 3's` inside of their parent  `Level 2's`.

The way to define the difference between what their parents is is by the order in which they appear in the array.

```
//Array Structure currently
Level 1
Level 2
Level 3
Level 3
Level 3
Level 2
Level 3
Level 3
Level 2

//Desired Array
Level 1
    Level 2
        Level 3
        Level 3
        Level 3
    Level 2
        Level 3
        Level 3
    Level 2
```

**Code**
Currently I am doing this to get what I need:

```
$i = 0;
$singleArray = [];
foreach ($jamie['Row'] as $value){
    $item  = 0;
    $id = $value->Cell->Data;
    $level = substr ($value->Cell[1]->Data, 6, 1);
    $name = $value->Cell[2]->Data;

    /* Start Level One */
    if($level==1){
        $singleArray[$i] = array(
            'key' => $i,
            'id'=>(string) $id,
            'level'=>$level,
            'name'=>(string)$name
        );
    };
    /* End Level One */
    /* Start Level Two */
    if($level==2){
        $reverseArray = array_reverse($singleArray);
        foreach($reverseArray as $key => $value) {
            if($value['level']==1){
                $reverseArray = $value['key'];
                break;
            }
        }

        $tempArray = array(
            'key' => $i,
            'id'=>(string) $id,
            'level'=>$level,
            'name'=>(string)$name
        );

        array_push($singleArray[$reverseArray],$tempArray);
    };
    /* ENdLevel Two */
    $i++;
}
```

Basically what i'm doing is, as i go through building up the array I and see which level it belongs to, then i take what we have so far of the array and reserve it until we find the first level 1, once we have a level one grab where that is in the array and stick that on the array item and insert the new array in there. This works for level 2 into level 1. Its level three that I can't see to get working :(

**Array**

```
 0 => 
  array (
    'key' => 0,
    'id' => '7',
    'level' => '1',
    'name' => 'About Me',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'key' => 1,
    'id' => '78',
    'level' => '2',
    'name' => 'My Conduct at Work',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'key' => 2,
    'id' => '270',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Dispute Resolution/Grievance',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'key' => 3,
    'id' => 'TBC',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Learn More',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'key' => 4,
    'id' => '77',
    'level' => '2',
    'name' => 'My Environment, Health & Safety',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'key' => 5,
    'id' => 'TBC',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Learn More',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'key' => 6,
    'id' => '238',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Policies and Guidance',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'key' => 7,
    'id' => '79',
    'level' => '2',
    'name' => 'My GSK Employment Journey',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'key' => 8,
    'id' => '274',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Changes in Role',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'key' => 9,
    'id' => '275',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Leaving GSK',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'key' => 10,
    'id' => '273',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'My Moves',
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'key' => 11,
    'id' => '272',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Starting at GSK',
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'key' => 12,
    'id' => '80',
    'level' => '2',
    'name' => 'My Personal Information',
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    'key' => 13,
    'id' => 'TBC',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Learn More',
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    'key' => 14,
    'id' => '276',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Manage my Personal Information',
  ),
  15 => 
  array (
    'key' => 15,
    'id' => '76',
    'level' => '2',
    'name' => 'My Talent, Performance & Development',
  ),
  16 => 
  array (
    'key' => 16,
    'id' => '266',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'My Development',
  ),
  17 => 
  array (
    'key' => 17,
    'id' => '268',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'My Learning',
  ),
  18 => 
  array (
    'key' => 18,
    'id' => '267',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'My Performance',
  ),
  19 => 
  array (
    'key' => 19,
    'id' => '75',
    'level' => '2',
    'name' => 'My TotalReward',
  ),
  20 => 
  array (
    'key' => 20,
    'id' => '287',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Learn More My Benefits',
  ),
  21 => 
  array (
    'key' => 21,
    'id' => '288',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Learn More My Pay',
  ),
  22 => 
  array (
    'key' => 22,
    'id' => '264',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'My Benefits',
  ),
  23 => 
  array (
    'key' => 23,
    'id' => '263',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'My Pay',
  ),
  24 => 
  array (
    'key' => 24,
    'id' => '265',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'My Recognition',
  ),
  25 => 
  array (
    'key' => 25,
    'id' => '81',
    'level' => '2',
    'name' => 'Time Off, Time & Attendance',
  ),
  26 => 
  array (
    'key' => 26,
    'id' => '281',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Flexible Working',
  ),
  27 => 
  array (
    'key' => 27,
    'id' => 'TBC',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Learn More',
  ),
  28 => 
  array (
    'key' => 28,
    'id' => '279',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Leave of Absence',
  ),
  29 => 
  array (
    'key' => 29,
    'id' => '280',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Time & Attendance',
  ),
  30 => 
  array (
    'key' => 30,
    'id' => '278',
    'level' => '3',
    'name' => 'Time Off',
  )
```

Comment: Is it a sorted array? I mean, like the one you showed above?

Comment: Check this out: http://kvz.io/blog/2007/10/03/convert-anything-to-tree-structures-in-php/

Comment: @Guy the array is sorted in a sense, in as much as its the order i need it to be in.

Comment: @ElGamed reading up on the link, looks promising :)

Comment: humm, trouble is this uses the key values to sort through and then, it has one delimiter... On my server I need to sort via a value and this changes every row... I think its just not possible tbh.

Comment: Anything is possible! :) It's just a little more challenging...